# overwrite a file then append

Tags: shell, loops

I have a loop in my script that will append a list of email address's to a file "$CRN". If this script is executed again, it will append to this old list. I want it to overwrite with the new list rather then appending to the old list. I can submit my whole script if needed. I know I could test if "$CRN" exists then remove file, but I'm interested in some other suggestions? Thanks.

```
    for arg in "$@"; do
            if ls /students | grep -q "$arg"; then
                    echo "${arg}@mail.ccsf.edu">>$CRN
                    ((students++))
            elif    ls /users | grep -q "$arg$"; then
                    echo "${arg}@ccsf.edu">>$CRN
                    ((faculty++))
    fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better do this :

```
CRN="/path/to/file"
:> "$CRN"

for arg; do
        if printf '%s\n' /students/* | grep -q "$arg"; then
                echo "${arg}@mail.ccsf.edu" >> "$CRN"
                ((students++))
        elif printf '%s\n'/users/* | grep -q "${arg}$"; then
                echo "${arg}@ccsf.edu" >> "$CRN"
                ((faculty++))
        fi
done
```

- don't parse `ls` output ! use bash `glob` instead.  `ls` is a tool for interactively looking at file information. Its output is formatted for humans and will cause bugs in scripts. Use globs or find instead. Understand why: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs
- "Double quote" *every* expansion, and anything that could contain a special character, eg. "$var", "$@", "${array[@]}", "$(command)". See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes  http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments and http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words
- take care to false positives like `arg=foo` and `glob` : `foobar`, that will match. You need `grep -qw` then if you want word boundaries. UP2U

Comment: Added `grep -qw` case